# I have two sets of numbers. I want to calculate the percentage difference of their averages.

Tags: average, percentages

I have two sets of numbers like this

```
a = [400, 2934, 450, 675]
b = [700, 314, 9433, 579]
```

I need to calculate the percentage difference of their averages. The goal is to be able to say set b has improved or deteriorate
by a certain percentage in average. I am using the percentage difference formula as this:

```
(|ΔV|)/((ΣV)/nV))*100
```

Meaning if I have only 400 and 700 I would have this:

```
(|400-700|)/((400+700)/2)*100 = 54.5455%
```

However, I have no idea how to get the percentage difference of their averages. I searched online and read many articles but couldn't find an answer. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Could please consider adjusting your math into mathjax?

Comment: Where did you get that “percentage difference” formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Percent Difference is defined as $$\% \text{ Difference}=\dfrac{\lvert\,X_{acc}-X_{exp}\,\rvert}{X_{acc}}*100.$$ Where $X_{acc}$ is an accepted value and $X_{exp}$ is an experimental value measured quantitatively. We may adapt this formula for our needs accordingly.

Therefore, if you are choosing a certain average, say $700$ as the average to compare to $400$, you would have $$\% \text{ Difference}=\dfrac{\lvert\,700-400\,\rvert}{700}*100=42.857\%.$$ Therefore, the average $400$ is $42.857\%$ different from your average $700.$

As pointed out in a comment by David K., you can say there was a drop in $42.857\%$ from $700$ to $400$, or just a $-42.857\%$ difference from $700$ to $400$.

Comment: If I had an accepted value of $700$ and then observed a value of $400$, I would calculate a negative percentage change from $700$ to $400.$ In general I would reverse the order of subtraction in the formula.

Comment: @DavidK The formula usually has an absolute value sign.

Comment: Does it? I don’t recall that from any of my textbooks. The direction of change is usually as important as (or even more important than) the magnitude; why would you throw that information away?

Comment: I would like to vote for both the response and the comments, but I don't have enough points yet! Thanks for the response @JohnColtraneisJC ! Not only did I learn something, I also learned how to write formula in stack exchange! You rock!

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @mnsr No problem man!